# opening files in mounted directory from within apps

Tags: applications, mount, file-management, remote-access

I have successfully mounted a local network location on to `/sdcard/routersd` ; I can successfully browse within this mounted directory and do copy/delete operations. My purpose of creating that is for me to be able to browse and open my PDFs, office docs, and media files from within my Android apps such as Adobe Reader, QuickPic, WPS Office and etc.

The problem is that those apps cannot see files and directories available in that mounted directory! Alternatively, when I try to open `/sdcard/routersd/for-example.pdf` from within a file manager, then selecting Adobe Reader, Google Doc, WPS Office, etc. as the openner, I receive errors like "This file could not be accessed. Check the location or the network and try again.", "File cannot be opened", and "File no longer exists : File may be renamed, moved, cleared, or deleted by other programs." What is this error for? How can this aim be achieved (opening network files from within apps that originally can browse only local files)?

Comment: What is available (e.g., Samba, FTP, SSH, etc.) at the remote machine that you're mounting on your device using network? Show us what you've used to mount the remote directory as a local drive.

Comment: @Firelord , Unknowingly, the problem doesn't exist with regard to pictures but still continues with PDFs. the local network storage location is **192.168.0.1/sdcard** (which is refering to sdcard in my portable router). I'm using this code for mounting : `su -c 'busybox mount -t cifs //192.168.0.1/sdcard /sdcard/routersd -v -o user=admin,pass=xxxxxxxx'`

Comment: How are the permissions set?

Comment: @Roh_mish , The permission for the directory and its files is `drwxrwxrwx`

Comment: [You can find the answer to this questin here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134880/how-to-enable-android-apps-to-browse-user-mount-points-in-mnt)